# Criar diferentes índices para diferentes buscas - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, índices

Olá,

Em um outro momento eu precisava obter posts similares a um específico no blog que estou desenvolvendo, sendo essa similaridade regida pelas tags usadas em cada post. Usando o MongoDB, consegui isso criando um índice nas tags, dessa forma:

```
db.mypostscollection.createIndex({"tags": "text"});
```

E funciona bem, faço a busca dos similares assim:

```
MyPostModel.find({
    $text: {
      $search: tags.replace(/\,/, ' ')
    }
  }, {
    score: {
      $meta: "textScore"
    }
  })
  .sort({
    score: {
      $meta: "textScore"
    }
  })
```

Contudo, agora precisa buscar os posts por seus títulos e conteúdo, e pensei em fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
 db.mypostscollection.createIndex({"title":"text","subtitle":"text","mainContentText":"text"});
```

Mas como já criei o índice *$text* não o posso fazer novamente.

Então como crio as pesquisas de forma independente? Uma para as tags, outra para o *match* de conteúdo.

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual o motivo de você estar usando índices do tipo [text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)? A ideia principal deles é procurar texto dentro de um atributo string do documento. Eles são custosos para criar e manter. Além disso, como você percebeu, só se pode criar um índice text por collection.

Você poderia usar um índice normal para esses campos. Ao invés de especificar "text" no tipo, você pode colocar 1 para índices crescentes, e -1 para decrescentes. Em campos string o banco vai usar esses índices para pesquisas com regex, desde que sejam para o ínicio/fim da string (regex começando com ^ ou terminando com $).

Não conheço o teu schema e padrões de acesso da aplicação. Mas creio que o índice do tipo texto seria interessante para o corpo post, você tem mais palavras buscáveis nesse campo. Não esquecendo do custo alto (performance e espaço em disco) para manter esse índice!

Para os posts similares você pode usar o [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) (considerando que seu campo de tags é um array).